# Writing a factorial tail recursive function in Scala

Tags: scala, function, recursion, functional-programming, tail-recursion

I'm trying to write a tail recursive function in the below way, but the compiler is throwing an error:

Too many arguments for method apply: (v1: Int)Int in trait Function1
        else factorial(x-1, x*acc)

I had tried replacing Function1 with Function2 and gave Function2[Int, Int, Int] = new Function2[Int, Int, Int]

But it still threw me the same error. Can someone point out where i'm going wrong?

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
var factorial: Function1[Int, Int] = new Function1[Int, Int] {
    @tailrec override def apply (x:Int, acc:Int=1): Int = {
        if (x<=1) acc
        else factorial(x-1, x*acc)
    }
}

factorial(5)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You `apply` inside `Function1` must take only one param, when you are passing two.

You can rewrite it as follows:

```
var factorial: Function1[Int, Int] = new Function1[Int, Int] {
  def apply (x:Int): Int = {
    @tailrec def loop(x: Int, acc: Int = 1): Int = {
      if (x<=1) acc
      else loop(x-1, x*acc)
    }
    loop(x)
  }
}
```

Comment: You can read a bit more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234682/in-scala-can-you-make-an-anonymous-function-have-a-default-argument) about a reason why anonymous function doesn't support a default argument.

Answer (score 2):

`Function1` represents a function with a single parameter (the second one is for the output)

So you need to define your apply method with a single parameter, and then, inside it, do the recursion using a nested function:

```
  import scala.annotation.tailrec
  var factorial: Function1[Int, Int] = new Function1[Int, Int] {

    override def apply(x: Int): Int = {
      @tailrec
      def go (x: Int, acc: Int = 1) : Int = {
        if (x<=1) acc
        else go(x-1, x*acc)
      }
      go(x)
    }
  }
  factorial(5)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37566013/6214495) which is a great explanation of your issue. Your problem is *you are trying to define `apply` as tail-recursive but you are not calling itself in the recursive call*, you are calling `factorial` instead.

First off, you should use `Function2` as your type for apply likewise:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

import scala.annotation.tailrec
var factorial: Function2[Int, Int, Int] = new Function2[Int, Int, Int] {
    @tailrec override def apply (x:Int, acc:Int=1): Int = {
      if (x<=1) acc
      else apply(x-1, x * acc)
    }
}
```

And then, if you get the error `could not optimize @tailrec annotated method apply: it contains a recursive call targeting a supertype`, you should call `apply` recursively as for a function to be tail recursive it always should be called exactly itself as the last statement.

```
scala> factorial(5, 1)
res3: Int = 120
```

Answer (score 0):

#### `Function2` take 3 type parameters. Last one is the output type.

#### Scala REPL

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

 val fac: Function2[Int, Int, Int] = new Function2[Int, Int, Int] {
    def apply(v1: Int, v2: Int): Int = if (v1 == 1) v2 else apply(v1 - 1, v1 * v2)
  }


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

fac: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>

scala> fac(5, 1)
res1: Int = 120
```

You can syntactic sugar (function syntax in scala using `=>`) instead of using interface/trait Function2.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val fac: (Int, Int) => Int = (acc, c) => if (c == 1) acc else fac(acc * c, c - 1)


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

fac: (Int, Int) => Int = $$Lambda$1092/1204822967@5c83ae01

scala> fac(1, 5)
res0: Int = 120
```

Comment: Looking at answers from both pamu and Yevhenii Popadiuk, the mistake I did was when calling the function, since i was declaring the acc=1, when calling the function i was just using fact(5), which caused the problem. But I don't understand even when acc=1 has been declared, when calling it, why should i still pass the value?

Comment: You cannot use default value syntax in this case as it is trait instance creation. You can do this in case of normal function declaration

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you like some syntactic sugar, you can write it:

```
  val f: (Int) => BigInt = (x) => {
    if (x <= 1) 1
    else x * f(x - 1)
  }

  println(f(30))
```

Or true tail-recursive function:

```
  val f: (Int) => BigInt = (x) => {

    @tailrec
    def helper(x: Int, acc: BigInt = 1): BigInt = {
      if (x <= 1) acc
      else helper(x - 1, x * acc)
    }

    helper(x)
  }

  println(f(30))
```